# Как перемещать длинные картинки в Android

Tags: android

Есть длинная картинка, часть которой должна отображаться всегда, и в определенный момент нужно переместить картинку вниз. Перемещать я умею, проблема в том, что если засовывать в обычный ImageView, то картинка просто сожмется, а не вытянится вверх как мне надо. Нужно сделать вот так:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:clipChildren="false" //Добавить
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-200dp" //Смещение
    />

</LinearLayout>
```